# creating a email client using google api

Tags: api, gmail, email-client

Consider me as a complete newbie on web development and please answer my question.
My boss recently handed me a project. it was to make an web based email client to get CVs from people.this should have a GUI which can receive e-mails, read emails, send emails,access folders from the gmail account we have.i searched everywhere and found out that Google API is the way to do this.is it correct? if so how do i do that? i don't have any prior knowledge about how to use the APIs. but I'm willing to learn.please help me
thanks

Comment: There are many third party SMTP client libraries out there which can help you download, read and see the attachments of emails. Do you have a particular choice of programming language?

Comment: hi @pwned 
the requirements have been changed.i have updated my question as well. i want to make a web based email app so that it can sync our company mail and display the emails.how should i do that? what are the technologies i may require? please answer.thanks

Comment: well since you didn't specify any language or framework of preference, I'd say go for a ruby on rails based application using [a gmail gem like this](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail). It uses the google API wrapped in ruby syntax for easy development.

Comment: hi @pwned
i tried it using php with imap..but i had a issue with large email accounts.it took alot of time to display.i prefer if i can do it with javascript. but i dont know if thats possible.i looked into your suggestion.can i use ruby to make a web page and a host it in aserver..? my boss wants the staff to be able to access it through web and use it..is it possible with ruby? if so it would be really great if you could help...thanks alot for taking time to answer..your kind of my savior atm..lol.thanks..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have made my question possible by using php with imap.accessing emails based on folders and getting necessary data such as email address, senders name, email id, etc was pretty simple
use the php commands that starts with imap_funcName...hope this helps someone..:)